# LINQ find first occurrence before and after target value of equal distance

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking if there is an efficient way to do this via LINQ:

I have a list of values e.g. {98, 98.5, 99, 99.5, 100, 101, 102}

I would like to supply a reference value and then find the closest value before and after that are equal distance apart.

Example 1) reference value is 99 -> I'd like to find 98.5 and 99.5

Example 2) reference value is 100 -> I'd like to find 99 and 101 (note, it's skipping 99.5)

If there are no 2 values of equal distance apart from the reference value, it should return null

Comment: you should show us what you've tried... code will get the bunch going

Comment: This is rather broad and your specifications aren't very clear.  For example, why does an input of `99` return `98.5, 99.5` and not `98, 100`?

Comment: "closest" possible values to reference value that are equal distance apart. I'll add "closest" to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var items = new[] {98, 98.5, 99, 99.5, 100, 101, 102};
var target = 99;

var result = items.Distinct() // Omit duplicates.
                  .Select(Value => new {Value, Distance = Math.Abs(target - Value)}) // pair the Value with the distance.
                  .GroupBy(x => x.Distance) // Group the values by distance.
                  .Where(x => x.Count() > 1) // Omit the values where there is no symmetrical distance.
                  .OrderBy(x => x.Key) // Order them by distance.
                  .FirstOrDefault(); // Take the first one. 

if (result != null)
    foreach (var item in result)
        Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
```